# Undo fixing of broken dependencies and updates

Tags: apt

I wanted to install screen and after command `sudo apt-get install` screen I got error and information that I should command `apt-get install -f`.

So I executed:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install screen
```

It was fine and screen worked. After reboot ubuntu hangs. Any one of tty does not work and I only see bliding dash. If I booting to recovery mode and command `shutdown now` in root command prompt then ubuntu transits to tty1 and tty1-6 works properly, but tty7 has only blinking dash.

I suspect that updates or fixing of broken dependencies case this problem. 
Is there some way to recover state before that?

Comment: possible duplicated http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the tty problem is due to a dependency conflict, more probably when you forced the installation of screen it did installed the program but it's not working properly.
Try to remove, boot into recovery mode and execute this:

```
apt-get remove --purge screen
```

(You won't need sudo since you're in recovery mode).

Then, you can try to install screen again, and paste here what exactly is the output of the error when you try a normal install like this:

```
sudo apt-get install screen
```

Comment: It did not help